# Connecting multiple USB RNDIS devices to PC in the same network

Tags: networking, usb

Running an Ubuntu 12.04.4 I have the following issue:
I want to connect multiple USB RNDIS devices to one PC.
Additionaly, every device should be in the same network.
**The problem** is that only one device is reachable via the PC.

My following example is for two USB RNDIS devices. One with the IP `192.168.0.15` and the other with `192.168.0.16`
The two USB devices are detected correctly with the following `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
# The device for 192.168.0.15
auto usb0
iface usb0 inet static
address 192.168.0.200
netmask 255.255.255.0

# The device for 192.168.0.16
auto usb1
iface usb1 inet static
address 192.168.0.201
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

If I connect the devices and run `ifconfig` it looks as follows:

```
usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 22:d0:9c:4f:65:77  
          inet Adresse:192.168.0.200  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::20d0:9cff:fe4f:6577/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:5 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:50 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:308 (308.0 B)  TX-Bytes:8803 (8.8 KB)

usb1      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 8e:f4:be:bf:6d:1c  
          inet Adresse:192.168.0.201  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::8cf4:beff:febf:6d1c/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:0 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:29 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:5929 (5.9 KB)
```

But here comes the drawback. Unfortunately only the `usb0` device is reachable. So if I type in `ping 192.168.0.15` everything works fine. But if I try `ping 192.168.0.16` nothing happens, even with `ping 192.168.0.16 -I usb1` literally nothing happens:

```
$ ping 192.168.0.16 -I usb1
PING 192.168.0.16 (192.168.0.16) from 192.168.0.201 usb1: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.0.16 ping statistics ---
45 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 44351ms
```

`ping` does even not say, that the host is unreachable (note the `time 44351`). The next strange thing is, that packages have been send (not the TX in ifconfig regarding usb1) but never recieved (not the RX in ifconfig regarding usb1).

Comment: first of  all did you disable network manager ?second, you should watch carefully the ip given by ifconfig 192.168.0.200 and 192.168.0.201, my guess is that you have a network error somewhere...

Comment: Hi Kiwy, network manager is disabled (for sure). I cannot figure out any error. The devices run well, if they are pluged in seperatly.

Comment: add `route-n` output please

Comment: Is this still a problem? Could you add the output of `route -n` as requested by @Kiwy?